# Loading a Class that extends another class using a Class Loader

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, classloader

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to load classes at runtime to get access to there annotations. I'm able to do this just fine when it doesn't extend or implement a class that I don't have access to. When this happens I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception and cannot get access to the class object and therefore cannot use the reflection API to get the annotations. Is there anyway to get access to the annotations in the class under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or the [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) library to scan the class bytecodes rather than trying to load the class.

Comment: I'd recommend [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) as it is probably more Java-like syntax then every other byte-manipulation framework out there

Comment: @RomanVottner Sure, I'm fine to suggest that instead, thanks.

Comment: [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) worked perfectly, thank you very much!!